# Unable to view data in Mosaic Dataset in full extent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic-dataset

I have created a Mosaic Dataset containing Raster Datasets which point to TIF files shared at a remote Windows server.

I can see that the Dataset created is fine as I could see grid cells but I could not see the actual Image from Full extent. I have to zoom it to see the images.

Comment: There is an option create thumbnails or similar. Right click on mosaic to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

There is a Geo Processing tool called Build Overviews. It defines and generates overviews on a mosaic dataset.

Visit below mentioned URL to find out more :-

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-overviews.htm